# Argument error due to ruby 3.0 deprecation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I recently upgraded the ruby version of my app to `3.0`. After which multiple test cases were failing but all of them were of the same kind.
For ex, `post :create, :params => { :identifiedBy => { :label => epc }, :model => { :productId => productId } }`
or `post :create, :params => create_params_kc_with_tid`

All of the failing test cases gave the same error

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

I am not so sure about the root cause but I am suspecting it is happening due to the recent deprecation in ruby 3.0 i.e., `Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated`

I am not so sure how to fix it. Please help me with the same.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a single case of the problem, we need to see the actual error copy/pasted, and the file with the test generating that error with the line number marked that the error is indicating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:params => {}` is a `Hash` of `{params: {}}` to use kwargs (keyword arguments) the syntax is similar but distinctly different to the parser.

To resolve this (and clean up your code a bit) change all instances of `:symbol => value` to be `symbol: value`.

For Example:

```
post :create, :params => { 
                 :identifiedBy => { :label => epc }, 
                 :model => { :productId => productId } }
```

becomes

```
post :create, params: { 
                 identifiedBy: { label: epc }, 
                 model:  { productId: productId } }
```

Now `params` will be treated as a keyword argument, additionally I would change all the old Hash rocket usages where the key is a symbol (as I did in my recommended change)